# Reducing a huge code on many activityes

Tags: android, format, reduce

i need help to reduce this damn code.I know this is a hell. Sorry about my english
 Problems:

1. I have read about parcelable, have no ideia how to use tough (cause i have an arraylist inside my object)
2. Can i create a generic type of onclicklisteners (in this case)
3. I have tried assynctask, but the main ui is blocked and i get a black screen
   and 4 last changing the orientation 3 times results in exception on my dialog

Any answer will help a lot.

```
public class AndroidfeedtsxActivity extends Activity implements ViewFactory {
 private int evento = 0;
 private boolean isfavorite = false;
 private Handler handler = new Handler();
 private ProgressDialog dialog;
 private List<Noticia> exists;

 /** first method called */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     noticias();
 }

 /*/
  * --------------------------------------------------------------------
  */

 /*
  * /starts the main screen, and the imagebuttons
  */
 private void telaPrincipal(final List<Noticia> naoFormatada) {
               //close progress dialog
     dialog.dismiss();
     handler.post(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {

             //Formating my xml
             final List<Noticia> lista = new Formatador()
             .Formatar(naoFormatada);




             if (!(lista.isEmpty() || lista== null)) {
                 exists = naoFormatada;
                 setContentView(R.layout.main);

                 evento++;

                 ImageButton ImgBtnEsportes = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImgBtnEsportes);
                 ImgBtnEsportes.setClickable(true);

                 ImageButton ImgBtnTodas = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImgBtnTodas);
                 ImgBtnTodas.setClickable(true);

                 ImageButton ImgBtnComunidade = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImgBtnComunidade);
                 ImgBtnComunidade.setClickable(true);

                 ImageButton ImgBtnPolicia = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImgBtnPolicia);
                 ImgBtnPolicia.setClickable(true);

                 ImageButton ImgBtnFavoritos = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImgBtnFavoritos);

                 // show all news
                 ImgBtnTodas.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View arg0) {
                         isfavorite = false;
                         telaMensagens(lista);

                     }
                 });

                 // show sport news only
                 ImgBtnEsportes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View arg0) {
                         isfavorite = false;
                         telaMensagens(Categorizador(lista, "Esportes"));
                     }
                 });

                 // show police news only
                 ImgBtnPolicia.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View arg0) {
                         isfavorite = false;
                         telaMensagens(Categorizador(lista, "Polícia"));
                     }
                 });

                 // shows comunity news only
                 ImgBtnComunidade.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View arg0) {
                         isfavorite = false;
                         telaMensagens(Categorizador(lista, "Comunidade"));
                     }
                 });

                 // show the favorited news
                 ImgBtnFavoritos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View arg0) {
                         NoticiaDAO banco = new NoticiaDAO(getBaseContext());
                         try {
                             List<Noticia> noticias = banco.getLista();
                             banco.close();
                             isfavorite = true;

                             telaMensagens(noticias);
                         } catch (ParseException e) {
                             Log.e("Erro ao tentar abrir Favoritos", " " + e);
                         }
                     }
                 });
             } else {
                 Toast t;
                 t = Toast
                         .makeText(
                                 getBaseContext(),
                                 "Não foi possível obter as noticias no momento...\nTente novamente mais tarde.",
                                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                 t.show();
                 setContentView(R.layout.main);
                 evento++;
                 ImageButton ImgBtnEsportes = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImgBtnEsportes);
                 ImgBtnEsportes.setClickable(false);
                 ImageButton ImgBtnTodas = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImgBtnTodas);
                 ImgBtnTodas.setClickable(false);
                 ImageButton ImgBtnComunidade = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImgBtnComunidade);
                 ImgBtnComunidade.setClickable(false);
                 ImageButton ImgBtnPolicia = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImgBtnPolicia);
                 ImageButton ImgBtnFavoritos = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImgBtnFavoritos);
                 ImgBtnPolicia.setClickable(false);
                 ImgBtnFavoritos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View arg0) {
                         NoticiaDAO banco = new NoticiaDAO(getBaseContext());
                         try {
                             List<Noticia> noticias = banco.getLista();
                             banco.close();
                             isfavorite = true;

                             telaMensagens(noticias);
                         } catch (ParseException e) {
                             Log.e("Erro ao tentar abrir Favoritos", " " + e);
                         }

                     }
                 });

             }

         }
     });
 }
```

/*/
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

```
 /*
  * / call the screen with the news as a list
  */
 public void telaMensagens(final List<Noticia> noticias) {

     evento--;
     // controll the number of times the backbutton is pressed

     /*
      * / call the xml screen for the list
      */
     setContentView(R.layout.lista);

     /*
      * / declarando um listview em java que chama o listview do xml
      */
     ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
     if (!noticias.isEmpty()) {
         // declarando arrayadapter que adapta uma arraylist em uma lista
         /*
          * / android dependendo do método tostring()
          */
         ArrayAdapter<Noticia> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Noticia>(this,
                 R.layout.listadjust, noticias);

         /*
          * / setando o adapter
          */
         lista.setAdapter(adapter);

         /*
          * / permitindo que a lista seja clicável
          */
         lista.setClickable(true);

         /*
          * / qual ação a lista tomará ao clicar em um item
          */
         lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                     int arg2, long arg3) {
                 telaLeitura(arg2, noticias);
             }
         });
     } else {
         Toast t;
         t = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                 "Não há noticias para essa categoria no momento...",
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
         t.show();

     }
 }

 /*/
  * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  */

 /*
  * / call the news reader screen and stantiate the imagebuttons to see images and */add to favorites
  */
 public void telaLeitura(int posicao, List<Noticia> noticias) {
     setContentView(R.layout.telaleitura);
     TextView texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     final Noticia atual = noticias.get(posicao);
     texto.setText(atual.getContent());
     texto.setClickable(true);
     final ImageButton getImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
     ImageButton favoritos = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
     ImageButton Excluir = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
     if (!isfavorite) {
         favoritos.setVisibility(0);
     } else {

         Excluir.setVisibility(0);
     }
     /*
      * / controll delete button
      */
     Excluir.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidfeedtsxActivity.this);
             builder.setMessage("Deseja excluir esse favorito?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                             NoticiaDAO banco = new NoticiaDAO(getBaseContext());
                             banco.excluir(atual.getId());
                             banco.close();
                             Toast t;
                             t = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                     "Favorito Excluido com sucesso.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                             t.show();
                             noticias();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Não", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                             dialog.cancel();

                        }
                    });
             AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
             alert.show();

         }
     });

     /*
      * / controlling favorites insertion
      */
     favoritos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
             final NoticiaDAO banco = new NoticiaDAO(getBaseContext());

             try {
                 List<Noticia> Noticias = banco.getLista();
                 if (!Noticias.contains(atual)) {
                     //Cria alerta dialogo confirmando...
                     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidfeedtsxActivity.this);
                     builder.setMessage("Deseja adicionar noticia aos favoritos?")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                     banco.inserir(atual);
                                     Toast t;
                                     t = Toast
                                             .makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                                     "Adicionada aos favoritos!",
                                                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                     t.show();
                                     banco.close();
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("Não", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                     dialog.cancel();
                                     banco.close();
                                }
                            });
                     AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                     alert.show();

                 } else {
                     Toast t;
                     t = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                             "Notícia já está nos favoritos.",
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                     t.show();
                     banco.close();
                 }
             } catch (ParseException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }


         }
     });

     /*
      * /if the news have images
      */
     if (atual.getImages().size() > 0) {
         getImageButton.setVisibility(0);

         // oque o botão fará quando clicado
         getImageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 if (atual.getImages().size() > 0) {
                     // cria a intenção de chamar galeria, e inicia a
                     // activity galeria
                     Intent it = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                             GalleryTSX.class);
                     it.putStringArrayListExtra("Lista",
                             (ArrayList<String>) atual.getImages());
                     setIntent(it);
                     startActivity(it);
                 }
             }
         });
     }
 }

 /*
  * / controll backbutton when pressed twice(non-Javadoc)
  * @see android.app.Activity#onKeyDown(int, android.view.KeyEvent)
  */
 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {

         if (evento < 2 && evento > 0) {
             Toast t;
             // Toast é um alerta do sistema
             t = Toast.makeText(this, "Pressione mais uma vez para sair",
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
             t.show();
         }
         if (evento > 1) {
             //Inicia serviço de alerta de Noticias Novas
             startService(new Intent(this, UpdateService.class));
             finish();

         }
         noticias();
         return true;
     }

     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }



 /*
  * / Controll news categorizer
  */
 public List<Noticia> Categorizador(List<Noticia> lista, String categoria) {
     List<Noticia> categorizada = new ArrayList<Noticia>();
     for (Noticia noticias : lista) {
         if (noticias.getCategory().equalsIgnoreCase(categoria)) {
             categorizada.add(noticias);
         }
     }
     return categorizada;
 }

 /*
  * / must be implemented for gallery usage(non-Javadoc)
  * @see android.widget.ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory#makeView()
  */
 @Override
 public View makeView() {
     ImageView iView = new ImageView(this);
     iView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
     iView.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(
             LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

     return iView;
 }



 /*/
  * (non-Javadoc)creates the menu
  * @see android.app.Activity#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)
  */
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
     return true;
 }

 /*/
  * (non-Javadoc) create a option in the menu "update"
  * @see android.app.Activity#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)
  */
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     switch (item.getItemId()) {

     case R.id.text:
         this.exists=null;
         noticias();
         break;

     }
     return true;
 }

 // controlls if must be updated or not
 public void noticias() {
     dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Aguarde...",
             "Baixando noticias, por favor aguarde...", false, true);
     if(this.exists==null || this.exists.isEmpty()){
         new Thread() {
             /*/
              * (non-Javadoc) Pegar As noticias do RSS e fazer parse
              * @see java.lang.Thread#run()
              */
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 try {
                     List<Noticia> noticias = new ArrayList<Noticia>();
                     URL url = new URL(
                             "http://www.tudosobrexanxere.com.br/index.php/rss");
                     SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                     NoticiaHandler handler = new NoticiaHandler();
                     SAXParser saxParser= factory.newSAXParser();
                     saxParser.parse(url.openStream(), handler);
                     noticias = handler.getMessages();
                     telaPrincipal(noticias);
                 } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
                     Log.e("Exception no Parser de ParserConfiguration",
                             "Exception" + e1);
                     Toast t;
                     // Toast é um alerta do sistema
                     t = Toast.makeText(AndroidfeedtsxActivity.this, "Problema ao obter notícias\nPor favor, use o menu para atualizar...",
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                     t.show();
                     if(exists!=null){
                         telaPrincipal(exists);
                     }
                     else{
                         telaPrincipal(new ArrayList<Noticia>());
                     }

                 } catch (SAXException e1) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     Log.e("Exception no Parser de SaxException", "Exception"
                             + e1);
                     Toast t;
                     // Toast é um alerta do sistema
                     t = Toast.makeText(AndroidfeedtsxActivity.this, "Problema ao obter notícias\nPor favor, atualize as noticias...",
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                     t.show();
                     if(exists!=null){
                         telaPrincipal(exists);
                     }
                     else{
                         telaPrincipal(new ArrayList<Noticia>());
                     }

                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     if(exists!=null){
                         telaPrincipal(exists);
                     }
                     else{
                         telaPrincipal(new ArrayList<Noticia>());
                     }
                     Toast t;
                     // Toast é um alerta do sistema
                     t = Toast.makeText(AndroidfeedtsxActivity.this, "Problema na sua conexão com a Internet\nPor favor, tente novamente mais tarde...",
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                     t.show();
                     Log.e("Exception no Parser de IO", "Exception" + e);
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     if(exists!=null){
                         telaPrincipal(exists);
                     }
                     else{
                         telaPrincipal(new ArrayList<Noticia>());
                     }
                     Toast t;
                     // Toast é um alerta do sistema
                     t = Toast.makeText(AndroidfeedtsxActivity.this, "Problema ao obter notícia\nPor favor, atualize as noticias...",
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                     t.show();
                     Log.e("Exception no Parser", "Exception" + e);
                 }

             }

         }.start();

     }else telaPrincipal(exists);

 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't know, sorry
2. You can create a single onClickListener a couple of ways. The main thing is to identify which button was clicked, so you can do the appropriate action. There are a couple of options. Either you can use view.setTag() and view.getTag():

   ```
   ImageButton ImgBtnEsportes = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImgBtnEsportes);
   ImgBtnEsportes.setClickable(true);
   ImgBtnEsportes.setTag("Esportes");

   ImageButton ImgBtnTodas = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImgBtnTodas);
   ImgBtnTodas.setClickable(true);
   ImgBtnEsportes.setTag("Todas");

    // etc

   OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            String tag = ((String)arg0.getTag());

            if(tag.equalsIgnoreCase("Esportes")){

                isfavorite = false;
                telaMensagens(Categorizador(lista, "Esportes"));

            } else if(tag.equalsIgnoreCase("Todas")){
                isfavorite = false;
                telaMensagens(Categorizador(lista, "Todas")); 
            }

        }


   };

   ImgBtnEsportes.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
   ImgBtnTodas.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
   ```

or you can use the auto-generated view id's:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

         int viewID = arg0.getId();

         if(viewID == R.id.ImgBtnEsportes){

                         isfavorite = false;
                         telaMensagens(Categorizador(lista, "Esportes"));

         } else if(viewID == R.id.ImgBtnTodas){
             isfavorite = false;
                         telaMensagens(Categorizador(lista, "Todas")); 
         }

    }
```

3 I would recommend using AsyncTask, despite all its problems. Override `onPublishProgress` in AsyncTask, and put any code that changes the UI in there. When you need to change the UI, call `publishProgress` from inside `doInBackground`

4 When you change the orientation, android basically re-starts the activity (calls `onCreate` again). This is probably what is causing you threading issues. Put `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your android manifest file inside activity tag. This will allow you to intercept orientation changes by overriding the method `onConfigurationChanged` in Activity. You then put the code for setting all the onClickListeners, setting up all the views etc in `onCreate`, so that it only gets called once, when the user first starts the Activity. Then if you need to do anything specific when the user changes orientation, you do it in `onConfigurationChanged`

I think once you get the threading sorted, it will make other things a lot easier

---

Edit: Ok, time to solve the threading

The only thread that is allowed to update the UI in android is the main thread (also called the UI thread). This is the thread that calls onCreate() when your activity starts.

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is used to create threads in Android and allow those threads to ask the UI thread to update the UI. So..

First create your AsyncTask as an inner class of your activity. It must be public or android can't access it to run it. In `doInBackground()` of the AsyncTask, put the SAXParser. When the parser finishes parsing, call `publishProgress()`. This will cause `onProgressUpdate()` to be called by the UI thread in its next pass

In `onProgressUpdate()`, put your call to `telaPrincipal()`. This will mean `telaPrincipal()` will get called by the UI thread when the parsing is complete

In `nocitas()`, replace `new Thread(){ etc }.start()` with `new CustomAsyncTask().execute()`

In `telaPrincipal()`, do not use a thread at all. I.e.

```
 private void telaPrincipal(final List<Noticia> naoFormatada) {
      //close progress dialog
      dialog.dismiss();


     //Formating my xml
     final List<Noticia> lista = new Formatador()
     .Formatar(naoFormatada);

     if (!(lista.isEmpty() || lista== null)) {
         exists = naoFormatada;
         // etc

}
```

Comment: wow, now that's a great help man!, well, i think the only issue left is about passing my object through another activities (so yeah parcelable or Gson must do... acepting sugestions) and reducing activity code even more.

Comment: 1- Still no ideia 2- Solved: gratefull to Spoon Thumb 3- use asynctask as inner class? Help needed 4- will depend on 3

Comment: updated my answer with regards to threads and AsyncTask. My understanding is that you want to have a thread busy reading an rss feed and then update the app when a SAX parser finishes parsing the feed